# Can we run MERGE Statements if the source and destination databases are on different servers

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

The title is the question. Will be very helpful if some one can also point to a link if at all it is possible.

And also, can we use a CTE in the Merge statement? Or we need to think of an alternative like temp table or table variable?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The target of a merge can not be a remote table but the source can be. And you can use a CTE in the [merge](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx) statement.

You can do something like this:

```
with S as
(
  select ID,
         Name
  from ServerName.DBName.dbo.TableName
)
merge LocalTable as T
using S
on T.ID = S.ID
when not matched then
  insert (ID, Name) values(S.UnitID, S.Name);
```

Comment: Well I don't know if this is a relevant to ask or not, however,why the target of a merge can not be a remote table?

Comment: @user1025901 - I don't know why it's not allowed.